# How can get value of dropdownlist is number?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I used `ngValue` but it still return a string value.

This is my code in html:

```
<form [formGroup]="EditMovieForm" (ngSubmit)="Update()">
      <select formControlName="authorId" (ngModel)="selectedId" >
                    <option ngValue=0>--Select--</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let author of authors"
                            ngValue={{author.id}}> {{author.name}}</option>
      </select> 

 </form>
```

This code in ts file:

```
export class MoviesComponent {  
  selectedId: number;
  
  Update(){
     var formdata=this.EditMovieForm.value;
  }
}
```

`authorId` still return a string value when click update:

```
authorId: "1"
```

How can get value of dropdownlist is number?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [value] in your option for setting the numeric value

```
<form [formGroup]="EditMovieForm" (ngSubmit)="update()">
      <select formControlName="authorId" (ngModel)="selectedId" >
                    <option [value]="0">--Select--</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let author of authors"
                            [value]="author.id"> {{author.name}}</option>
      </select> 

 </form>
```

Comment: I had try your code, but it still return string authorId: "1"

Comment: with your code change value to ngValue  , it will ok.

Comment: @DT try this [ngValue]="author.id" it will work for sure